# select the value from the nth position above

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to calculate something by getting the corresponding value from a field (let's say abc256) to which i must subtract the value from the same column but 249 rows above (let's say abc7) and then multiply it by 100 into a new column in a temporary table (only for displayin the output).

How to count from the current value 249 fields above? 
I already ordered the list as it should be by 2 columns asc.

So the query which orders my list looks like:

```
select [rN] ,[rD],[r],[rId]
from [someName].[dbo].[some_table]
where rN like '%bla%'
and rD >= 'yyy-mm-dd'
```

**EDIT**: **`order by rD asc, rID asc`**

a pseudocode of what i need is:

```
[(case when rN like 'something' then newSomething = (r.value - r.count(249).value))*100) as newSomething)]
  FROM [someName].[dbo].[some_table]
```

then i tried

```
select [rN] ,[rD],[r],[rId]
from select (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by key ASC) AS rownumber,
        r)
    from
[someName].[dbo].[some_table]
where rownumber = r -249
  where rN like '%bla%'
    and rD >= 'yyy-mm-dd'
```

I should mention that i need to to a repetitive process of this (after each 249 rows i am calculating using the current value - the value from 249 rows above). And i will have 12 cases for `rN like 'something1' ...'something12'`

How to get this to work? 
Thanks

Comment: "nth row above" by what sort criteria? Without `ORDER BY` the order of the records is arbitrary and undefined.

Comment: i am sorting the list by the name and date. I checked against the excel in which the values are exported to. The list is now ordered corectly. I just to figure out a way in which i could count 249 positions above the value in a field and use that in my formula (sorry if i didn't formulate my question in the right way, I'm quite new to sql)

Comment: I can't see that in the code above. Please post your real code as far as possible.

Comment: i forgot to add : order by rD asc, rID asc. Edited now

Comment: How are we supposed to know what name and date is and what you are grouping by?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add. It's there now

Comment: No it is not.   You don't define the value field.

Comment: this is what i have so far. I don't want necesarly code from you. An idea of what i could do. Any suggestions? Also, can't post my real code since it has sensitive info. This is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adapt this to your specific needs, but whenever I am posed with the "Compare a column to the one nth one before it" problem, I revert to CTE expressions and then do a self-join. I've thrown together a quick example to get you started. I hope you find it useful.

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
IF OBJECT_ID('Table_1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Table_1
GO

-- CREATE A TABLE FOR TESTING
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Num1] [int] NULL,
    [Num2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- FILL THE TABLE WITH VALUES
DECLARE @cnt INT; SET @cnt = 0
WHILE @cnt <=10000
    BEGIN
      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
      INSERT INTO Table_1 (Num1, Num2) VALUES (@cnt, @cnt * 1000)
    END
GO 

-- DO THE SELECT
; With RowedTables AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id ASC) As R,
        T1.*
    FROM Table_1 T1)

SELECT
    RT1.Num1 - RT2.Num1 AS SomeMath, 
    RT1.*,
    RT2.*
FROM RowedTables RT1 JOIN RowedTables RT2 ON RT1.R = RT2.R - 10
```

Comment: Np, note that you will have some special cases to deal with around the beginning and end of the datasets (R1, R2....R249) in which there is nothing to join against.